# How can I change the order of N-Panel tabs?

Tags: add-on, customization, panel

I want to be able to re-order the items and add-on tabs in the N Panel. For example, I use the add-on "Asset Management" a lot, so I would like it to appear first or second in the panel. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Could you please add a little more to your question to help us be able to answer it more precisely? It would help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate more. I'm talking about the tabs in the N-Panel. Press N and you will see them. I want to be able to change their order.

Comment: Their order is managed by the order in which they get registered (chronogically). So in a way you can rearrange add-on-specific panels because you have a say in which one gets registered first (but only once when you actually install the add-on), but I don't think you can easily re-arrange the default ones (Tool, View, Item, which will always come first). There is no drag-n-drop functionality for it but I'm pretty sure this has been suggested to the developers. This is not what you asked but have you explored the "Pin" functionality of the panels ? (Right click > Pin or SHIFT + Click)